# Assembly - Segfault with subprogram

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, frequency

I'm trying to debug why I'm getting a segfault in my subprogram.

It happens on the ret line at the end of the subprogram - as in once the 0x00 byte is reach at the end of the sentence.

Main :

```
                .data
string:         .string "aaaaaaaaaaa"
endofstring:    .space  8
msg:            .string "%c occurs %d times \n"

                .text
                .global main

main:

    mov     $string,%rsi            #rsi = string storage
    mov     $0x61, %ah              #storage of a 
    mov     $0x65, %al              #storage of e
    mov     $0x69, %bh              #storage of i
    mov     $0x6F, %bl              #storage of o
    mov     $0x75, %ch              #storage of u


#Case A
    mov     %ah,%cl                 #1 byte register for cmp later on.
    mov     $0, %rax                #initialize count to 0
    call    FREQ                    #Generate %rax value for 


    mov     %rax, %rdx              #count for printf (2nd argument)
    mov     $msg, %rdi              #format for printf(1st argument)
    mov     %r8, %rsi               #ch for printf (3rd argument)

    xor     %rax, %rax              #reset %rax for printf output

    call    printf                  #print the frequency value of the ch in string


#Case E
    mov     %al,%cl
    mov     $0, %rax                #initialize count to 0
    call    FREQ

    mov     %rax, %rdx              #count for printf (2nd argument)
    mov     $msg, %rdi              #format for printf(1st argument)
    mov     %r8, %rsi               #ch for printf (3rd argument)

    xor     %rax, %rax              #reset %rax for printf output

    call    printf                  #print the frequency value of the ch in string

#Case O
    mov     %bh,%cl
    mov     $0, %rax                #initialize count to 0
    call    FREQ

    mov     %rax, %rdx              #count for printf (2nd argument)
    mov     $msg, %rdi              #format for printf(1st argument)
    mov     %r8, %rsi               #ch for printf (3rd argument)

    xor     %rax, %rax              #reset %rax for printf output

    call    printf                  #print the frequency value of the ch in string

#Case I
    mov     %bl,%cl
    mov     $0, %rax                #initialize count to 0
    call    FREQ

    mov     %rax, %rdx              #count for printf (2nd argument)
    mov     $msg, %rdi              #format for printf(1st argument)
    mov     %r8, %rsi               #ch for printf (3rd argument)

    xor     %rax, %rax              #reset %rax for printf output

    call    printf                  #print the frequency value of the ch in string
#Case U
    mov     %ch,%cl
    mov     $0, %rax                #initialize count to 0
    call    FREQ

    mov     %rax, %rdx              #count for printf (2nd argument)
    mov     $msg, %rdi              #format for printf(1st argument)
    mov     %r8, %rsi               #ch for printf (3rd argument)

    xor     %rax, %rax              #reset %rax for printf output

    call    printf                  #print the frequency value of the ch in string

    jmp done


done: 

    ret
```

Subprogram:

```
    .text 
    .globl  FREQ



FREQ:   
    #subprogram body
Start:
    cmpb    $0,8(%rsi)              #check for end of the string
    je      donefreq

loopfreq:
    cmp     %cl, 8(%rsi)            #compare first string char with vowel 
    je      incrementstring         #if equal - jump to increment_string
    add     $1, %rsi                #if not - increment string
    jmp     Start                   #jump to loop to check for end of string status/next char

incrementstring:
    add     $1, %rsi                #increment to next string character
    add     $1, %rax                #add 1 to frequency of character
    jmp     Start

donefreq:
    ret
```

Not sure why this happens. - I wish debugging gave a bit more info :(

Does anyone have an idea as to why this occurs? I followed exactly the outline of my notes for the callee function so I'm at a loss as to where the problem is in the callee

Comment: Your subprogram keeps adding to _RSP_ so by the time it gets to the `ret` the return address is no longer at the proper place on the stack and `ret` will crash trying to return to some semi random memory location.

Comment: `mov  $string,%rsp` this i very bad too. You need to read about how the stack works and parameter passing. Your code has significant problems.

Comment: So to counter this I should keep a count of the times I increase RSP then sub that count from RSP before returning?

Comment: I thought we already established you have typo `rsp` for `rsi` ...

Comment: I have read on stack usage/parameter passing - I guess I'm just not getting some of the stuff. :(

Comment: @Jester Looks like I missed a few :( edited~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `%rsp` as a pointer to your string. You are corrupting the return address in the stack so your `ret` instruction tries to jump to some bogus address. Use `%rsi` or another general purpose register. The Stack Pointer is not a register you can use as you wish.

Comment: Thank you - this cleared up the confusion I had. Much appreciated - I've switched to using $rsi for string storage as suggested by the magnificient @Jester. Ty all.